# Showing loading bar while inserting values into a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, loops, asynchronous

I am basing this code on this example http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2009/11/15/asynchronous-processing-in-asp-net-mvc-with-ajax-progress-bar.aspx
Using MVC3, C#, jQuery, Ajax ++

My html

```
<div>
   <a href="#" id="startProcess">Start Long Running Process</a>
</div>
<br />
<div id="statusBorder">
    <div id="statusFill">
    </div>
</div>
```

the javascript part part of the html

```
    var uniqueId = '<%= Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>';

    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#startProcess').click(function () {
            $.post("SendToDB/StartLongRunningProcess", { id: uniqueId,
                                 //other parameters to be inserted like textbox

                                                             }, function () {
                $('#statusBorder').show();
                getStatus();
            });
            event.preventDefault;
        });
    });

    function getStatus() {
        var url = 'SendToDB/GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            if (data != "100") {
                $('#status').html(data);
                $('#statusFill').width(data);
                window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
            }
            else {
                $('#status').html("Done");
                $('#statusBorder').hide();
                alert("The Long process has finished");
            };
        });
    }
```

A whole class to help

```
public class ProgressBarManager
{

    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the process status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The process status.</value>
    private static IDictionary<string, int> ProcessStatus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyLongRunningClass"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ProgressBarManager()
    {
        if (ProcessStatus == null)
        {
            ProcessStatus = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the long running action.
    /// This is how it was in sample code. Not used anymore.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    //public string ProcessLongRunningAction(string id)
    //{
    //    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    //    {
    //        Thread.Sleep(100);
    //        lock (syncRoot)
    //        {
    //            ProcessStatus[id] = i;
    //        }
    //    }
    //    return id;
    //}

    public void SetStatus(string id, int value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            ProcessStatus[id] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public void Add(string id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            ProcessStatus.Add(id, 0);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public void Remove(string id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            ProcessStatus.Remove(id);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public int GetStatus(string id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (ProcessStatus.Keys.Count(x => x == id) == 1)
            {
                return ProcessStatus[id];
            }
            else
            {
                return 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the controller, and this is where I probably do something wrong.

```
    delegate string ProcessTask(string id);
    ProgressBarManager longRunningClass = new ProgressBarManager();
    //Some global variables. I know it is not "good practice" but it works.
    private static int _GlobalSentProgress = 0;
    private static int _GlobalUsersSelected = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the long running process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public void StartLongRunningProcess(string id,
                                        //other parameters
                                        )
    {
        longRunningClass.Add(id);

        int percentDone = 0;
        var batchId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var costd = cost.ToDecimal();
        int sent = 0;

        IEnumerable<BatchListModel> users;

        users = new UserService(_userRepository.Session).GetUsers(
                //several parameters)

        foreach (var c in users)
        {
            try
            {
                var usr = _userRepository.LoadByID(c.ID);

                var message = new DbLog
                {
                    //insert parameters
                };

                _DbLogRepository.Save(message);
                sent++;

                //MyLog.WriteLine("Sent = " + sent); This is  1 more each time it loops
                //MyLog.WriteLine("GlobalUsersSelected = " + _GlobalUsersSelected); This one is set in another function not shown.

                double _GlobalSentProgress = (double)sent / (double)_GlobalUsersSelected * 100;
                //MyLog.WriteLine("SentProgress = " + _GlobalSentProgress);

                if (percentDone < 100)
                {
                    //percentDone = doSomeWork();
                    percentDone = Convert.ToInt32(_GlobalSentProgress);
                    //MyLog.WriteLine("percentDone = " + percentDone); This one shows same as GlobalSentProgress except the decimals are removed
                    longRunningClass.SetStatus(id, percentDone);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MyLog.WriteLine("ERR:" + e);
            }
        }
        longRunningClass.Remove(id);


        //Under here is how it was done in the example tutorial. 
        //I think these should be implemented somehow.
        //This may be the root of my problem

        //ProcessTask processTask = new ProcessTask(longRunningClass.ProcessLongRunningAction);
        //processTask.BeginInvoke(id, new AsyncCallback(EndLongRunningProcess), processTask);


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends the long running process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The result.</param>
    public void EndLongRunningProcess(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ProcessTask processTask = (ProcessTask)result.AsyncState;
        string id = processTask.EndInvoke(result);
        longRunningClass.Remove(id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current progress.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public ContentResult GetCurrentProgress(string id)
    {
        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        var currentProgress = longRunningClass.GetStatus(id).ToString();
        return Content(currentProgress);
    }
```

Anyone know what can be wrong? Any help hugely appreciated. I have been stuck for days.

Some breakpoints that is supposed to update the "progress" is not entered until the insertions is 100% done. Right now the div with the progress bar never shows up.

EDIT:
In the loop doing the insertions, I do have this calculation:

```
double _GlobalSentProgress = (double)sent / (double)_GlobalUsersSelected * 100;
```

Then I convert the _GlobalSentProgress to a normal int in the

```
percentDone = Convert.ToInt32(_GlobalSentProgress);
```

so it no longer has any decimals any longer.

If only I could send this "percentDone" variable (wich is showing perfectly how many percent I have come in the insertion) asynchronous into the "data" variable in javascript every single time it loops, it would work. Then "data" would do it's "statusFill" all the time and show the bar correctly.

```
    function getStatus() {
        var url = 'SendToDB/GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            if (data != "100") {
                $('#status').html(data);
                $('#statusFill').width(data);
                window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
            }
            else {
                $('#status').html("Done");
                $('#statusBorder').hide();
                alert("The Long process has finished");
            };
        });
```

But I got to be honest, this is the first time I deal with asynchronous variable so I am very lost on how to do this stuff.

Comment: Can you tell us what isn't working, specifically?

Comment: The div that is supposed to show the progress never shows up. The "updating progress" parts is not entered before the insertion into the database is complete. The process is just running, inserting into the DB, then showing the "alert("The Long process has finished");" in the end.

Comment: It is best not to post huge blocks of code. Very few people will take the time to sort through all that code. Try describing the specific errors you are getting and what debuging you have tried so far. Only post the code that you think is relevant to the problem and many more people will take the time to try and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If i encounter such a problem the first thing i do is set breakpoints or debugger (in js) and see what parts of code is doing something.

You say that your statusbar is never showing that is if you look at the [Jquery.post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it states

> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

that is because your query did not succeed it will never show.
So the first thing it to look where it is going wrong inside your code (C#)

Comment: I believe the "function () {
                $('#statusBorder').show();
                getStatus();" is not entered before the part above it is complete in the javascrpit part. Meaning it is not "shown" before the whole process is complete, and it is too late.

Comment: @user2107630 I understand that. That is the answer to your question. It will only show the div if the .post succesfully completes. If not it will not show. That is why i said take a look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get designer help to show progress bar,
Suppose you div element with some CSS

```
<div id="divProgressBar" >/div>
 $(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('#startProcess').click(function () {
        $('#divProgressBar').show();//My code here
   }
}

function getStatus() {
    var url = 'SendToDB/GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        if (data != "100") {
            $('#status').html(data);
            $('#statusFill').width(data);
            window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
        }
        else {
            $('#status').html("Done");
            $('#statusBorder').hide();
            $('#divProgressBar').hide();//My code here
            alert("The Long process has finished");
        };
    });
}
```

You can also use third party JS to block UI.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/